# Instantiating ChangeNotifierProvider with Parameter

Tags: flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to instantiate a provider with an id passed through a route, the db call keeps failling as the id passed to it is blank not the value passed in.

*(Feel free to ignore this next wordy bit if it isn't appropriate for your preffered method of communication.)* Thank you in advance for any help, Im a newbie and have been trying for a while to get this working. Its a fairly standard pattern of handling data, but I can't find the standard way(s) to implement it. I have tried instantiating the provider in an init state with no luck. I have researched some options but Future Provider doesn't do what I need as that only returns static information.

Here is the ChangeNotifier I am using:

```
class MetaDataBrain extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Meta> _meta = [];
  late String _dataId;

  List<Meta> get metaData => _meta;
  String get dataId => _dataId;

  set dataId(String dataId) {
    _dataId = dataId;}


  MetaDataBrain({required String dataId}) {
    _dataId = dataId;
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    List<Map<String, Object?>> json = await DataDatabase.instance.getAllByFk(tableName: tableMetaData, columnName: MetaFields.fk, fk: _dataId);
    MetaHelper helper = MetaHelper();
    _meta = helper.fromJsonList(json);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Here is the stateful page where the provider is instantiated:

```
class LoadingDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingDetailScreen({super.key, required this.dataId});
  final String dataId;

  @override
  State<LoadingDetailScreen> createState() => _LoadingDetailScreenState();
}

class _LoadingDetailScreenState extends State<LoadingDetailScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<MetaDataBrain>(
        create: (context) => MetaDataBrain(dataId: widget.dataId)),
    ], child: const DetailScreen());
  }
```

Here is the DetailScreen:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("this is a title")),
      body: SafeArea(child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10), child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: Consumer<MetaDataBrain>(builder: (context, metaList, child) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemCount: metaList.metaData.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {return const SizedBox(height: 10);},
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {return InformationCard(title: metaList.metaData[index].title, line1: metaList.metaData[index].description);}
        );})),
      ]))
    ));
  }
}
```

Here is the call to the DB

```
  Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> getAllByFk({required String tableName, required String fk, required String columnName}) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final maps = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $columnName = ?', [fk]);
    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {return maps;} else {throw Exception('nothing found in $tableName with fk $fk in $columnName');}
  }
```